# Identify who created a particular AWS resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

We are using multiple AWS services from last few years. Now we have many aws resources which are created but doesnt have created by tag. We would like to tag each on our resources (which supports tagging) with w created by tag, specifying name/email of the user who created it. Is it possible to to do through any API (Boto3) or Console. As per my research it seems impossible but I would like to confirm with the community if there is any way to do it.

Comment: Have you checked AWS CloudTrail ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution but you can create a custom solution by using CloudWatch Events and Lambda. I implemented a similar solution only for EC2 resources last year.

1. Create event rules for the resources you want to tag. For example, the following event rule calls the  target Lambda function whenever a/an instance/volume/snapshot/AMI is created.

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateVolume",
      "RunInstances",
      "CreateImage",
      "CreateSnapshot"
    ]
  }
}
```

2. The target Lambda function parses the event data. You need to extract all resource IDs and principal data and make an API call to tag the resources. The following example uses Boto3 EC2 API; resource_ids, username and principal are variables extracted from the event.

```
ec2.create_tags(Resources=resource_ids, Tags=[{'Key': 'Owner', 'Value': username}, {'Key': 'PrincipalId', 'Value': principal}])
```

You can extend this solution to tag other resources too.